# ajax load and php server request uri

Tags: php, ajax

I am loading "myscript.php" to a div.

When i use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in myscript.php, it prints myscript.php's url.

how can i print the page's url that myscript.php is loaded into ?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

maybe this?

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```